# No value given for one or more required SQL parameters

Tags: sql, excel, vba

I am getting No value given for one or more required parameters error from the SQL string I am trying to execute in Excel VBA. I dont have a where clause, why is this happening?

```
SQL = "SELECT [AVL$].ItemID, [AVL$].SKU, [AVL$].ItemDesc, [SKU Order$].Site, [SKU Order$].Store FROM     [AVL$] " & _    
      " INNER JOIN [SKU Order$] on ([AVL$].SKU) = ([SKU Order$].SKU) "
```

Comment: What are the values of the `AVLS$` and `SKU Order$` variables? When you run SQL Profiler, what does the query look like when it is executed against the server? The SQL string itself appears to look fine. Where's the line of code where you attempt to execute it?

Comment: Post the query that is working in SQL, as @SchmitzIT said, your VBA query looks alright.

Comment: Try to execute "SELECT * FROM [AVL$]" and "SELECT * FROM [SKU Order$]" and check the returned field names against the field names you are using in your query. The error indicates that you are trying to get a field that does not exist in a table". I assume you are running the query against sheets and not a database.

Comment: I had fixed the problem with the earlier query but now when I add another Inner join I get the error again. The SQL is    SQL = "SELECT [AVL$].[ItemID], [SKU Order$].[Store], [AVL$].[SKU] FROM ([AVL$] " & _
      " INNER JOIN [SKU Order$] ON [AVL$].[SKU] = [SKU Order$].[SKU] ) " & _
      " INNER JOIN [SKU AVL$] ON [AVL$].[SKU] = [SKU AVL$].[SKUM] " & _
      " ORDER BY [SKU Order$].[Store], [AVL$].[SKU], [AVL$].[ItemID]"